# Template class + virtual function = must implement?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, class-template

This code:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
     T t;

     void DoSomething()
     {
          t.SomeFunction();
     }
};

struct B
{
};

A<B> a;
```

is easily compiled without any complaints, as long as I never call `a.DoSomething()`.

However, if I define `DoSomething` as a virtual function, I will get a compile error saying that `B` doesn't declare `SomeFunction`. I can somewhat see why it happens (DoSomething should now have an entry in the vtable), but I can't help feeling that it's not really obligated. Plus it sucks.

Is there any way to overcome this?

**EDIT 2:** Okay. I hope this time it makes sence:
Let's say I am doing intrusive ref count, so all entities must inherit from base class Object. How can I suuport primitive types too? I can define:

```
template <typename T>
class Primitive : public Object
{
    T value;
public:
    Primitive(const T &value=T());

    operator T() const;

    Primitive<T> &operator =(const T &value);
    Primitive<T> &operator +=(const T &value);
    Primitive<T> &operator %=(const T &value);

    // And so on...
};
```

so I can use `Primitive<int>`, `Primitive<char>`...
But how about `Primitive<float>`? It seems like a problem, because floats don't have a `%=` operator. But actually, it isn't, since I'll never call `operator %=` on `Primitive<float>`.
That's one of the deliberate features of templates.

If, for some reason, I would define `operator %=` as virtual. Or, if i'll pre-export `Primitive<float>` from a dll to avoid link errors, the compiler will complain even if I never call `operator %=` on a `Primitive<float>`. If it would just have fill in a dummy value for `operator %=` in `Primitive<float>`'s vtable (that raises an exception?), everything would have been fine.

Comment: Well what's the point of having the function if you never call it? If it calls DoSomething on your type T instance then type T must implement a DoSomething method.

Comment: The point is, I may call DoSomething if it's appropriate, or I may not, dpending on the conetext. Ofcouse, if I actually call it then T must implement whatever's necessary. That's one of the more useful properties of templates.

Comment: This smells of bad design. :| What exactly are you trying to do? Not your detail goals, your task goals.

Comment: You can solve it pretty easily by requiring your clients to define a free SomeFunction(T&); function that you just call with SomeFunction(t);, and the call will select whatever function is available (as a fallback, your own one).

Comment: @litb: What if I want to use the template with a primitive type? I need the compiler to fill in a dummy thunk in the vtable.

Comment: @sold i don't understand what you mean. calling `SomeFunction` with, say, an `int` would work fine. In contrary, calling `t.SomeFunction()` (as it's now) with `t` being an int (dunno what you meant with a "primitive" otherwise) is ill formed.

Comment: If a type doesn't support an operation, it shouldn't appear in the interface. As for floats not having a modulo operation, see `fmod` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmod).

Comment: As for instantiation not being obligatory, see C++ 2003 standard, § 14.7.1 9: "An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function template, a member template, **a non-virtual member function**, a member class or a static data member of a class template that does not require instantia- tion. It is unspecified whether or not an implementation implicitly instantiates a virtual member function of a class template if the virtual member function would not otherwise be instantiated.'

Answer (score 2):

Put the virtuals into selectable base classes...

```
struct Jumper
{
    virtual void Jump =0;
};

struct Crawler
{
    virtual void Crawl() =0;
};

struct JumperCrawler:
    public Jumper,
    public Crawler
{
};

template<typename T, typename Methods>
class ICanBoostJumpingAndCrawling :
    public Methods
{
    T t;
};
```

Now you can use ICanBoostJumpingAndCrawling with Jumper,Crawler or JumperCrawler supplied as the Methods template parameter; realizing that you need to be derived from it so that you can implement Jumping and or Crawling in a subclass.

FYI, This makes the name "ICanBoostJumpingAndCrawling" completely misleading because it may or may not be able to do that; which means it should be renamed to something like "Booster".

Comment: Again, look at the question. The supplied code work OK. the problem is that if I define, say, ICanBoostJumpingAndCrawling::Jump as VIRTUAL, then the template machinery WOULD require me to define T::Jump() (which has nothing to do with the boosting). And that's what I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a bug, it's a feature -- seriously. At one time, most compilers would NOT compile the code, for exactly the reason you give. They've since been updated to compile it, partly because the standard requires it.

There was feature called "Concepts" in the C++ 0x standard for quite a while that would have allowed you to specify that T needed a member named 'SomeFunction', including its return type, argument type(s), etc.

Sadly, at the last meeting of the standard committee, they decided finishing up Concepts would delay the standard longer that most people wanted to wait, so they removed them.

Though it's not nearly as good, Boost does have a [Concept Checking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/concept_check/using_concept_check.htm) library that can do what you're asking about.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. he wants to be able to NOT declare DoSomething if the function is never called.

Comment: @shoosh, if i understood him correctly, he wants to declare it always, but he don't wan to get error messages if `T` doesn't have the function

Comment: I'm not sure you got the question. The problem is that the code WON'T compile, not that it will. The whole idea is that T might have a SomeFunction member, ot might not.

Comment: Yup, you're right -- I didn't read his question carefully enough.

Answer (score 0):

One way to overcome this is to specialize A for template argument B and not declare DoSomething()

```
template <>
struct A<struct B>
{
     T t;

};
```

Ofcourse this means that you now have to implement the entire A struct from scratch.

Comment: Not an option :P  What if I have an infinitely large set of classes that support SomeFunction, and an infintely large set of classes that doesn't?

Comment: Then your executable size would be infinite and not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

So the compiler should be able to work out within the compilation unit just what is in use.  As soon as you start to involve multiple compilation units it no longer has the limited scope and takes the necessary step to ensure that all of the class can compile.

For exporting from a library don't force the pre export, you can ignore the warnings about not exporting the templates as long as you compile all the code with the same compiler the template will be compiled the same in all locations, only compile what is necessary within each compilation unit.

To work around the problem with virtual, then the best you can do is to defer the issue to some other class - don't put virtual in the template.

Perhaps

- addition of a 'traits' portion to your template would allow a cheap way out.
- use multiple inheritance to define the composite template, like using shims

ie.

```
template <typename T>
class Additive
{
public:
    Primitive<T> &operator =(const T &value);
    Primitive<T> &operator +=(const T &value);
};

template <typename T>
class Multiplicative
{
public:
    Primitive<T> &operator *=(const T &value);
    Primitive<T> &operator /=(const T &value);
};

template <typename T>
class Integers : public Additive<T>, public Multiplicative<T>;
```

I'd really go back and ask if your abstracting the right level of information for making the template.